# C realloc usage

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I'm trying to dynamically increase memory of an `int` array, However I'm having issues getting it to work. It isn't expanding and adding more elements to the array, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Please help!

```
int* fibs = NULL;

void genFibs(){
    int i = 1,curSize = 0,curNum = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    while(flag){
        if(curSize != 0 &&curSize != 1){
            curNum = fibs[curSize-2]+fibs[curSize-1];
        }else if(curSize-1 == 1){
            curNum = fibs[curSize-1]+fibs[curSize-1];
        }else{
            curNum = 1;
        }
        if(curNum<=10){
            curSize++;
            fibs = (int*)realloc(fibs,curSize*sizeof(int));
            fibs[curSize-1] = curSize;
        }else{
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
  }
}

void printFibs(){
    int size = sizeof(fibs)/sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d is: %d\n",i,fibs[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you allocated memory for `fibs` using `malloc()` or `calloc()` before `realloc()`? And what error exactly?

Comment: Is the infinite loop intended?

Comment: no this function im simply wanting to generate the fibs array.

Comment: @Xaqq theres more code, logic stuff, just showing the important realloc part

Comment: Also, what is going wrong? Can you tell us more? Because this looks fine

Comment: i try printing it after it generates it, it only prints out one element

Comment: then show the code you use for printing, aside from the infinite loop the reallocation code is fine

Comment: @nos refer to my edit, the i added more code to avoid an infinite loop.  Like i said before, its simply not adding more elements to my array when trying to realloc it.  So when I go to print it, it only prints one element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your print code is wrong. `sizeof(fibs)` will always be evaluated as `sizeof(int *)` because its just a pointer.

You have to find a way to pass the `size` to your `print` function. It could be, for example the first value of your array. But this is implementation detail and it's up to you.

EDIT: Changed `sizeof(void *)` to `sizeof(int *)` because pointer size may vary, as pointed out by pmg.

Comment: Ok, I was going off this post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c" Whats the difference between these two??? my array is technically the same is it not??

Comment: Just a FYI: `void*` and `int*` do not necessarily have the same size (and alignment requirements and padding and ...).

Comment: @pmg oO didn't know about that. Alignment requirements and padding can make sense, but the size. Do you have any links explaining why and when? I thought all pointer had the same size.

Comment: @Xaqq: They don't have to. They just have to be convertible to and from a `void *`.

Comment: @Xaqq: see [6.2.5/27 in the C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.5p27). *"Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements."*

Comment: Answer edited, feel free to re-edit if it's not accurate enough :)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(fibs)` is the size of the pointer `fibs` which is constant, therefore your printing function will always print the same number of elements